# How to select parents and grandchildren?

Tags: jquery, css, jstree

In the following tree I want to select only `PARENT` and `GRANDCHILD`:

```
<div class="jstree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a>PARENT</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a>CHILD</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a>GRANDCHILD</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The tree is created by the jQuery plugin "jsTree".

The following code works but I think there is a more elegant way to do this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".jstree a:not(.jstree > ul > li > ul > li > a)", function(event) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: If you don't have always the same content and can't add class or id on your element, I think you are doing it quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yWdEj/)**

Your selector is fine, here is a shorter one:

```
$('.jstree a:not(:eq(1))')
```

---

### NOTE

It's better avoid using selectors like the above one, or the selector you wrote yourself. **Instead select elements based on `id` or `class`.** Selecting elements based on hierarchical structure will break in large markups.

Comment: This was the one I was looking for. Great! But as you stated in your note I will use the classes (that I didn't mention in my question).

Comment: this wont work if the structure change if you use classes its better

Answer (score 4):

you can use class or id to simplify selecting

HTML :

```
<div class="jstree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a class="parent">PARENT</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a>CHILD</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a class="grandchild">GRANDCHILD</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('.parent, .grandchild').click(function(event) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: +1 for a reasoning, as any solution based on hierarchy will break as soon as the structure is changed (and it WILL be changed). But could you add an example to your answer?

Comment: After your suggestion I had a further look at the created code. GRANDCHILDREN alsways have the class="jstree-leaf".

Comment: With your hints I was able to optimize the code to                 `$(document).on("click", ".jstree a, .jstree-leaf a", function(event) {`. Do you think this one is better?

Comment: can you explain me what is the difference?

Comment: It's only the real classes that jsTree adds for you if you don't add classes by yourself. So I can use your hint without even have to fiddle with jsTree!

Comment: I choose the other answer because that was the selector I was looking for even if it is better to work with classes. Hope that's ok...

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, simply using HTML classes may be better than building complicated CSS selectors.

```
<div class="jstree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a class="tree-item">PARENT</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a>CHILD</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a class="tree-item">GRANDCHILD</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And then

```
$('.jstree .tree-item')
```

Comment: You're definitely right! jsTree gives me the class "jstree-leaf". I wasn't looking close enough...